# Pages legal text template

Tags: pages

I am trying to make a 28 line legal template in Pages 5.2 but I am having trouble making the boxes work. Does pages have a CA Superior Court template. If not, do you know if Microsoft for Apple has one. I have looked it up on line and there is no data on it.

<sup>MacBook Air 10.9.4</sup>

Comment: Please rephrase the title of your question. "MacBook Air 10.9.4" should be in the body of your question with an actual question in the title. Additionally, you are missing applicable tags such as "pages".

Answer (score 1):

For MS Office you can download the Template [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/legal-pleading-paper-28-lines-TC103992040.aspx):

[image: legal]